# How do I keep Adobe installers from self-destructing?

Tags: windows-7

Recent Adobe installers (Flash, Reader) seem configured to self-destruct after they're done running.  While this is great for most people, I prefer to keep copies of my installers handy so I don't have to re-download them for system rebuilds and such.

I've tried marking the install file as read-only, but it still self-destructs.  Is there a non-self-destructing version I can download somewhere, or another trick I should use?

Comment: Why not just make a copy before you run it?

Comment: @EBGreen It's unnecessarily tedious to do it (and remember to do it) *every* time I run it.

Comment: If you poke around enough at the adobe.com website, you can find them, especially in the product specific portions.

Comment: Burn it to an ISO, I guess. I would bet that it's also downloading the real installer, anyway; so finding a better installer would be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you keep your installation files but it would be handy to create a folder (on a network resource especially) where you pull each of them from and can categorize the folder, etc.

Go to the computer where you want to run the installer and open up your installer folder (lets say flash drive). You can select the program and hold the right mouse button and drag it to the desktop. Once you let go of the icon you will be prompted to either "Copy Here", "Move Here", "Create Shortcut Here" or Cancel.

If you select copy here you will be able to seamlessly make a copy that will "self-destruct." If you choose to do this make sure you get in a habit of right clicking!